# The return type 'ListView?' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.dart

Tags: android, flutter, listview, asynchronous, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to make an async method that returns a ListView, so to add it to the body of my Scaffold I used future builder, but got this error.

```
The return type 'ListView?' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.dart
```

This is my FuturuBuilder code:

```
FutureBuilder<ListView>(
          future: getWidgets(context, this.residents),
          builder: ((context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return snapshot.data
            } else {
              return new ListView();
            }
          }),
        )
```

The "getWidgets" is the method that returns a ListView with the Containers I need, the "return new ListView()" is just a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `!` to `snapshot.data`:

```
FutureBuilder<ListView>(
          future: getWidgets(context, this.residents),
          builder: ((context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return snapshot.data!; // add !
            } else {
              return new ListView();
            }
          }),
        )
```